# JavaScript - inheriting arrays with B.prototype=new A()

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

(I'm new to JavaScript). The following code:

```
function A() {
    console.log('Constructing A');
    this.a = new Array();
}
function B(x) {
    console.log('Constructing B');
    this.a.push(x);
    this.b = x;
}
B.prototype = new A();
b1 = new B(10);
b2 = new B(11);
console.log('b1', b1);
console.log('b2', b2);​
```

Results in b1 and b2 sharing *single* `this`.a array (but *different* `this.b`). It's like a shallow copy.

I don't quite understand what is the right way to create *separate* `this.a` arrays. I want them inherited because this is the logic of the code, besides I don't want to create them in each and every child object (and there are many child objects in my case).

Comment: see [Javascript property inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12027282/1048572) and [object members that are prototyped as arrays become shared by all class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4425318/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

I am very interested in the explanation of this problem. I've read @Niko`s duplicate question but it seems this is what makes the difference:

```
 function A() {
        console.log('Constructing A');
        this.a=new Array();
    }

    function B(x) {
        console.log('Constructing B');
        A.call(this); //--> calling the super() constructor creates a new array
        this.a.push(x);
    }

    B.prototype = new A();

    b1 = new B(11);
    b2 = new B(12);
    console.log(b1.a);
    console.log(b2.a);
```

Comment: Btw, why you need `B.prototype.constructor=B;` ?

Comment: Actually I think `B.prototype = new A();` also does nothing here. We don't use inherited this.a because it results in shared array, instead  we create a new array with super constructor.

Comment: JS is a beautiful but strange language. Too flexible so that normal OOP models always can be realised using various language hacks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> function A() {
>     console.log('Constructing A');
>     this.a = new Array();
> }
>
> function B(x) {
>     console.log('Constructing B');
>     this.a.push(x);
>     this.b = x;
> }
>
> B.prototype = new A();
```

This sets B's prototype as an instance of A. So all instances of B will have that instance of A on their `[[Prototype]]` chain.

In the B constructor, `this` references a new object that inherits from B.prototype, so `this.a` will reference the `a` property of `B.prototype`.

```
> b1 = new B(10);
```

So now `B.prototype.a` is `[10]`.

```
> b2 = new B(11);
```

and now `B.prototype.a` is `[10, 11]`.