# JavaScript inherit object as property

Tags: javascript, inheritance

What I currently have is an object, say b, that inherits an other object, say a. In object a I have an object as property(value). To clear things up:

```
var a = (function(){});

a.prototype.value = {
    val : "value a"
};

var b = (function(){
    this.value.val = "b";
    alert("object b: " + this.value.val);
});

b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
b.prototype.constructor = a;

new b();  // alerts "object b: b"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qqmtb846/

So far, so good. In object b I set the 'val' property of the 'value' object to another value. As expected the value is set(value is now 'b').

When I create another object, lets say c, I would expect that I get the original value('value a').

This is not the case. I'm sure this is due object reference.

```
var a = (function(){});

a.prototype.value = {
    val : "value a"
};

var b = (function(){
    this.value.val = "b";
    alert("object b: " + this.value.val);
});

var c = (function(){
    alert("object c: " + this.value.val);
});

b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
b.prototype.constructor = a;

c.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
c.prototype.constructor = a;

var ObjectB = new b(); // alerts "object b: b"
var ObjectC = new c(); // alerts "object c: b", I want that "object b: value a" is displayed
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eb6dsgv9/1/

I want to use an object as property in the super class because most of the values will be the same, but sometimes they have to change. There is still a referance despite it's a new instance.

1) Is this some kind of design weakness of JavaScript?
2) How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. In your constructor, `this.value` refers to the same object as `a.prototype.value`. You can *overwrite* `this.value` with a new value (which will leave `a.prototype` and its properties unchanged), but if you modify `this.value.val` you are modifying the `val` property of `a.prototype.value`.

I don't know what you mean by "design weakness" so I can't answer (1). This is simply the way JavaScript's prototypal inheritance works.

As for how to resolve it, I think you need to show us a more concrete example, as I don't think there's a simple one-size-fits-all solution to this. It could be resolved by using a deep copy instead of Object.create (though depending on how you do the deep copy you could lose any methods on the prototype, if it has any). To put it simply, if you need to modify the properties of the prototype's properties, you are going to run into a situation like this.

Probably a better solution is to have a separate set of data values for each instance. Having all your instances share the same set of data values is creating a mess in your situation.

Initialize the properties in `a`'s constructor:

```
var a = function () {
    this.value = {
        val: "value a"
    };
};
```

And then you can call that constructor from `b` and `c`'s constructor:

```
var b = function () {
    b.prototype.constructor.call(this);
    this.value.val = "b";
    console.log("object b: " + this.value.val);
};

var c = function () {
    c.prototype.constructor.call(this);
    console.log("object c: " + this.value.val);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eb6dsgv9/6/

Answer (score 2):

To add to JLRishe answer, you can make it work this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/eb6dsgv9/3/

```
var a = (function(){
    this.value = {
        val : "value a"
    }
});

var b = (function(){
    a.call(this);
    this.value.val = "b";
    alert("object b: " + this.value.val);
});

var c = (function(){
    a.call(this);
    alert("object c: " + this.value.val);
});

var ObjectB = new b();
var ObjectC = new c();
```

Here, 'value' is property of 'a', not a.prototype. In 'a' and 'c' constructors you create new, separate 'a', so you get a fresh 'value a' each time. The downside of it is you spend more memory for all 'a' instances.

**I based my answer on this:** [Javascript property inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027282/javascript-property-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

`Object.create(a.prototype)` creates a brand new object with it's `[prototype]` pointing to `a.prototype`.
Your new `ObjectB` and `ObjectC` are brand new objects with their `[prototype]` pointing to `c.prototype` resp. `b.prototype` which is 
your above new empty object with `[prototype]` pointing to `a.prototype`.

In your `b constructor` you try set the property `value.val` to "b" but ObjectB does not have such a property `value`. javascript than looks into b prototype which is again
empty object but has the link in it's `[prototype]` to another object which is `a.prototype`. that object has property `value` so it is set `value.val = "b"` .

In case of ObjectC the linking is the same, the only difference is that you are looking for property `value`. Javascript looks in every objects in the `[prototype]` chain until it finds the `value` property which is in your `a.prototype` object.

It is not design weakness of javascript it is it's strength actually. javascript is not OOP language.

Comment: JavaScript is an OOP language. It simply doesn't use class-based inheritance.

Comment: we can discuss that for hours. IMO delegation is not inheritance. It can be simulated though but it is not the same as OOP in Java.

Comment: Delegation vs. inheritance has nothing to do with whether a language is object oriented or not. JavaScript is an object oriented language. That's uncontroversial. It uses objects everywhere. From Wikipedia: "Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm that represents the concept of 'objects' that have data fields (attributes that describe the object) and associated procedures known as methods.  C++, Objective-C, Smalltalk, Delphi, Java, ***Javascript***, C#, Perl, Python, Ruby and PHP are examples of object-oriented programming languages."

Comment: my point is that fields are not inherited but delegated thus your object is not really an object the same way as understood in java. If you mention "associated procedures as methods" that does have some fundamentally different principles as well in contrast to the rest of the line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I definitely have to read more about prototype chain inheritance.